# Digital Clock on JavaScript not updating every seconds

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a digital clock using JavaScript and I am running into some problem. The digital clock does show up and the time is correct. However, it does not update every seconds, though the setinterval seems to be correct.

````
window.onload = pageLoad;
    function pageLoad(){

    var hours = document.getElementById("hoursOut");
    var mins = document.getElementById("minsOut");
    var secs = document.getElementById("secsOut");


    var dateVar = new Date();
    var currentHours = dateVar.getHours();
    var currentMinutes = dateVar.getMinutes();
    var currentSeconds = dateVar.getSeconds();
    var tiktok;

    
    function displayTime() {
        hours.innerHTML = currentHours + ":";
        mins.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":";
        secs.innerHTML = currentSeconds;
    }   



    function startClock(){
        displayTime();
        tiktok = setInterval(displayTime,1000);
    }

    
    }
    ```
````

Comment: you have to call the function at every second,you can use setTimeout for this

Answer (score 0):

You have to refactor your code to be like below.

```js
function startClock() {
  displayTime(); // Defined in your example
  setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
};

startClock();
```

Comment: It's not answering the question !

Comment: Please describe how it isn't working so that the answer can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a few changes. Just replace your code to the one below.

```js
function startClock() {
  displayTime();
  setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
};

startClock();
```

### Explanation

The mistake you have in your code is that you are initialising a variable on `setInterval`, which actually doesn't return anything (returns `void`).

You also never called the `startClock` function, which means the clock never started.

Comment: It's not answering the question !

Answer (score 0):

You need to update ***Date()*** value for each seconds

Put ***Date()*** inside you function ***displayTime()***

**Here example :**

```
function displayTime() {
    
    var dateVar = new Date();
    var currentHours = dateVar.getHours();
    var currentMinutes = dateVar.getMinutes();
    var currentSeconds = dateVar.getSeconds();
    
    hours.innerHTML = currentHours + ":";
    mins.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":";
    secs.innerHTML = currentSeconds;
    
}
```

**Full code :**

```
window.onload = () => {

    var hours = document.getElementById("hoursOut");
    var mins = document.getElementById("minsOut");
    var secs = document.getElementById("secsOut");
    var tiktok;

    function displayTime() {
    
        var dateVar = new Date();
        var currentHours = dateVar.getHours();
        var currentMinutes = dateVar.getMinutes();
        var currentSeconds = dateVar.getSeconds();
    
        hours.innerHTML = currentHours + ":";
        mins.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":";
        secs.innerHTML = currentSeconds;
    }   



    function startClock(){
        displayTime();
        tikstok = setInterval(displayTime,1000);
    }

    // call function
    startClock();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using , **setInterval** function .

*Thing you must know about setInterval :* setInterval function returns an **id** from which you can **stop** the setInterval using **clearInterval(id)** function , where id would be that id returned by setInterval function.

Also, you need to get current date value so, change your displayTime function like this :

```
function displayTime() {
        var dateVar = new Date();
        var currentHours = dateVar.getHours();
        var currentMinutes = dateVar.getMinutes();
        var currentSeconds = dateVar.getSeconds();
 
        hours.innerHTML = currentHours + ":";
        mins.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":";
        secs.innerHTML = currentSeconds;
    }
```

```
let id ;
function startClock() {
  displayTime(); 
  id = setInterval(displayTime, 1000);
};
startClock();
```

For example :

```js
let id ;
function startClock() {
  
  id = setInterval(()=>console.log(new Date().getMinutes()+"min" ), 1000);
};
startClock();
```

Comment: It's not answering the question !

Comment: How ? I have tried it ... it works

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. It seems like declaring the `var dateVar` `var currentHours` `var currentMinutes` `var currentSeconds`  outside of the function will lock in the values. That's probably why the code before only update once.

I have now declare the variables in the local scope but without any values. Then, declare the value of the variables inside of the function `displayTime()`, therefore it can still be update later on in the `startClock()` function.

```
 window.onload = pageLoad;
    function pageLoad(){

    var hours = document.getElementById("hoursOut");
    var mins = document.getElementById("minsOut");
    var secs = document.getElementById("secsOut");


    var dateVar;
    var currentHours;
    var currentMinutes;
    var currentSeconds;
    var tiktok;

    
    function displayTime() {
        dateVar = new Date();
        currentHours = dateVar.getHours();
        currentMinutes = dateVar.getMinutes();
        currentSeconds = dateVar.getSeconds();
        hours.innerHTML = currentHours + ":";
        mins.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":";
        secs.innerHTML = currentSeconds;
    }   



    function startClock(){
        displayTime();
        tiktok = setInterval(displayTime,1000);
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> You just need to change only one thing. To update time very second ,you just need to declare Date in-side DisplayTime Function. I have made few changes in your code.

```js
window.onload = pageLoad;
    function pageLoad(){

    var hours = document.getElementById("hoursOut");
    var mins = document.getElementById("minsOut");
    var secs = document.getElementById("secsOut");
    
    var dateVar;
    var tiktok;
    
    function displayTime() {
    dateVar = new Date();
    var currentHours = dateVar.getHours();
    var currentMinutes = dateVar.getMinutes();
    var currentSeconds = dateVar.getSeconds();
    hours.innerHTML = currentHours + ":";
    mins.innerHTML = currentMinutes + ":";
    secs.innerHTML = currentSeconds;
    }   
    function startClock(){
      tiktok = setInterval(displayTime,1000);
    }
    }
```